# Can we get Migrate to Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: feature-request

I'm seeing more than the occasional Ubuntu question float through here that relates to the Ubuntu Desktop OS (I'm going to try and find a list now)

Any chance we can get a "Migrate to Ask Ubuntu" button? Or is this not doable because it's a "partnered" site?

- https://serverfault.com/questions/206411/ubuntu-10-04-put-computer-to-sleep-when-inactive-for-4-hours
- [Why does htop have three load averages?](https://serverfault.com/questions/204753/why-does-htop-have-three-load-averages)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/204723/i-miss-the-network-icon-when-update-my-ubuntu-from-9-to-10-closed
- [DIs there any method to create my own sources.list file for Ubuntu and make it work well?](https://serverfault.com/questions/204713/dis-there-any-method-to-create-my-own-sources-list-file-for-ubuntu-and-make-it-wo)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/204422/virtualbox-windows-has-usb-driver-but-ubuntu-host-does-not-closed
- [How to run a command at boot up automatically?](https://serverfault.com/questions/202704/how-to-run-a-command-at-boot-up-automatically)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/204291/install-magick-in-ubuntu-10-10
- [Reboot after power failure for Mac running Ubuntu (server)](https://serverfault.com/questions/203522/reboot-after-power-failure-for-mac-running-ubuntu-closed)

Some of them have already been sent to SU but they would be (I believe) prime candidates for Ask Ubuntu. And that's just what I found with a very quick google search.

Answer (score 5):

Migration to a more specific stackExchange site is good.

IMO the "Ask Ubuntu" site is poorly named, since it implies that Ubuntu is vastly different to all other Linux distros.

Comment: Agreed but it's in the nature of *nix to fragment. Those in the Linux community that think it's somehow magically different from Unix are doomed to repeat Unix's history without even noticing... or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

This makes sense in its own rights, but I'm unsure how well it scales.

There's an issue with all these migration paths isn't there? Fragmentation and a difficult to use UI for the site which will put people off migrating questions.

Then there's knowing what to migrate to where. Should any and all questions go to the Ubuntu site (and how much would you have to lurk there to make that judgement)?. I'm already seeing questions that I think ought to be migrated to the webmaster SE, but unless I'm sure I don't want to migrate them.